# Prevent divs from "jumping" on scroll animation

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to animate two divs to slide into and out of the screen on scroll.  Scroll down and they move outward until they are out of view.  Scroll up and they slide back into view and stop at their original position specified in the CSS (I've used keyframes to achieve this on the page load).  The issue is that the divs jump roughly 500px from their original position as soon as the scroll movement is activated - i.e. the left div will jump over to the right side, then it will move over to the original specified CSS position **instead of starting at that position and moving off screen.**  As it stands, I only have the behavior set up for the left element as an example.

Unfortunately I'm unable to achieve any scrolling behavior in Codepen, and I don't want to push this live to my site with errors present.  Regardless, here is the code along with a link.  Any suggestions to the wording of the question as well as a solution to the issue are welcome and appreciated.

Here is a video of the issue.  - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2dAX2fPPN4&feature=youtu.be

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axpMwZ

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $horizontal = $('.about-left');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
      d = $(document).height(),
      c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c) * 18);

    var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

    $horizontal.css({
      'right': position
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  height: 300vh; // maximized to illustrate scroll
  width: auto;
}

.about-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  left: 18%;
  font-size: 300px;
  color: #15ad93;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
}

.about-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  right: 18%;
  font-size: 300px;
  color: #15ad93;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
}

@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <div class="about-left">[]</div>

  <div class="about-right">[]</div>

</div>
```

Comment: maybe its me, but the animation is happening only on page load...

Comment: @kukkuz Yeah that's the initial keyframes animation.  I've included a youtube link to the issue I'm having locally if you want to check it out. 
 Not sure why the same thing isn't happening here or in Codepen. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2dAX2fPPN4&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why your Codepen isn't showing scrolling

1) Absolute positioning requires a parent element with a `relative` position.  Probably while simplifying your code for this question and Codepen, your `.main` div lost that.  I've added it back.

2) When that still didn't get things working, I checked the dev console and noticed an error about `<script>` tags.  Your Codepen includes those in the JS panel, turns out they are not required, and actually cause a problem.  I removed them.

#### Why your animation is jumping

In short - it is just a math problem.  Your `.about-left` styling starts at `left: 18%;`.  On scroll that is overridden with the inline style using `right: <something>`, where `<something>` changes with scroll position.  The very first value of that `<something>` is drastically different than the initial `left: 18%;` position, so boom the element jumps across the screen.  I didn't try to puzzle through the details of your scrolling math to work out why, as there's a simpler fix.

The simplest option is to use a consistent positioning mechanism initially and on scroll.  For the initial position, `left: 18%;` can alternatively be expressed as:

```
right: calc(82% - 200px);
```

Just using 82% positions the *right* side of the box containing the element at 82% from the right hand side of the page, but we actually want the *left* side of the box there, so we have to subtract the width of that box.  In your Codepen that's 200px, though that probably depends on your final styling and might be different in your real code (eg your video shows a nice curly brace rather than the square ones in the Codepen).  You'll have to adjust as necessary.

Next, I updated your JS scrolling code to change position starting from that same initial position:

```
$horizontal.css({
    'right': 'calc(82% - 200px + ' + position + 'px)'
});
```

As long as your very first value of `position` is relatively small, the first move will be only a small distance from the starting point.

Note you have to use quotes around the `calc()`, and unquote the `position` JS variable.

[Updated, working Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXZNrO).  The animation is pretty fast, I mean it moves off screen quickly and in pretty large jumps, though of course you can tune the increment value by adjusting your math (watch the console for the logged position values).

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I was envisioning.  Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!    Here it is in action - [Inline Link] (http://www.justincefai.co)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to implement this same behavior for the very bottom of the page to keep the styling consistent, but I can't seem to figure out a way to keep the original position.  I know the solution above is intended for the top of the screen, so that won't work, but I've also tried combining scrollTop and windowHeight as a variable and enabling the behavior when the element is reached, but no luck.  It works for other elements higher on the page (move up on scroll etc), but not the bottom.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JustinCefai I had a look at your site and I think I see where you mean (`say-hi-l/r`?) but I probably can't see all the relevant code.  The `.visible` class doesn't seem to have any animation and I didn't notice any JS positioning, though I didn't try very hard to read your compressed CSS/JS :-) I did notice you have `$(tag)` where you should have just `tag`, though I don't think that would break anything.  I don't know of any reason the same approach would *not* work using the bottom as a reference instead of the top.  If you're still stuck maybe open a new question and I'll check it out :-)

Comment: Yep that's the part I'm talking about, I just haven't pushed it live because I've been applying for jobs and don't want any errors haha.  I'm basically just stuck trying to figure out how to use the bottom as a reference instead of the top (I'm guessing this is done within the math in the position variable?).  When I scroll to the top of the screen, the position says 0 in dev tools, and at the bottom it's something like 2.01326e+08px.  Any tips would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Your css:

```
.about-left {
  ...
  left: 18%;
  ...
}
```

Your js:

```
$horizontal.css({
    'right': position
});
```

Try to use in both "left" or in both "right".

or add to .about-left class "text-align: right;"